# Marrying an older woman

Tags: nikah, husband-wife, age

As by Islam can a Divorced older woman can marry a man whose age is equal or lesser than his granddaughter or grandson

Answer (score 1):

According to tradition, Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) was 25 years old when he married his first wife, [Khadījah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khadija_bint_Khuwaylid), who was about 40 years old at the time of marriage. Further, she had married before (Sunni view).

Given that, and the fact that there's no verse in the Quran that prohibits a man from marrying an older woman, I believe it is fine.